# Distance between the Sun and the nth planet

Tags: code-golf, math, restricted-source

### Challenge

Predict the distance between the Sun and the nth planet when using **any formula** that gives the same result as the [Titius–Bode law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titius%E2%80%93Bode_law): `d=(3*2^n+4)/10`.

**BUT WAIT**... there is one restriction:

- Your source code can not include any of the Titius–Bode law's digits
- So, your program can not contain the characters `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`

### Input

`n` a non-negative integer value:

- For Mercury `n` is -∞ no need to handle this case.
- `n=0` for Venus
- `n=1` for Earth
- `n=2` for Mars, and so on ...

### Output

Distance in astronomical unit between the Sun and the nth planet (decimal with at least one decimal place).

### Titius–Bode law

Distance in astronomical unit between the Sun and the nth planet is estimated by `d=(3*2^n+4)/10`.

### Example

```
0          --> 0.7
1          --> 1.0 or 1
11         --> 614.8
```

### Rules

- The input and output can be given [in any convenient format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- No need to handle **invalid input values**
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: The inputs and results you show do not match the formula.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thanks I just corrected the question

Comment: Hi, I've downvoted this challenge as it's basically a [Do X without Y](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/42963) challenge without much room for creative golfing.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork About "Do X without Y", yes. About "creative golfing", I'm not sure. Let's just see how the answer goes.

Comment: @Lynn it's done

Comment: I originally downvoted this challenge as I agree with AdmBorkBork's statement (and I still do), but have reverted that downvote simply because of the fun I had making my Whispers solution.

Comment: ["The number 3 is cursed.  Avoid it."](https://xkcd.com/1275/)

Answer (score 11):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
oxOÌÌT/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/v8L/cM/hnhD9//8NDQE)

**Explanation**

```
o          # push 2^input
 x         # pop a and push a, 2*a
  O        # sum stack
   ÌÌ      # add 2 twice
     T/    # divide by 10
```

Comment: literally. my. exact. solution.

Answer (score 11):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 22 bytes

```c
-Df(x)=((6<<x)+8.)/''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/18fK/jPlZlXopCbmJmnoalQrVBQBOSmKWgoqaYp6SikaRhralor1P7/l5yWk5he/F/XJU2jQtNWQ8PMxqZCU9tCT1NfXUQdAA)

Comment: I recommend to comment that there is a special character between `''`  Perhaps it is `'x14'`?

Comment: Looks like that `-D` is setting type to `double`? it seems to work on variable declarations too. I've never seen it before, where is it documented, and what other types are available? It's difficult to google and I can't find it on the PPCG tips for golfing in C question.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt `-D` looks like a compile time define in OP's "Try it online!"  Nothing to do with `double`.

Comment: @chux it seems you are correct. It would seem though, that this code would be more accurately described as a gcc command line option, rather than C. Certainly shorter than `#define` in the source file. Google found it documented at https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-d.html

Comment: @LevelRiverSt It's pointed in [meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14412/)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>29</s> <s>28</s> <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```hs
s=9-7
d n=(6*s^n+8)/5/s/s
```

<s>Nothing special, I'm afraid.</s> All allowed digits exactly once!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v9jWUtecK0Uhz1bDTKs4Lk/bQlPfVL9Yv/h/bmJmnoKtQm5igW@8QkFRZl6JgoqCRoqCjYqdpp2dbVpOZoFCFRCrKEQb6ukZGsb@BwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```javascript
n=>((6<<n)+8)/5/~-5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k5Dw8zGJk9T20JT31S/Ttf0f3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGgaamgr6@goKurp2CgZ45F6qsIZKsIbocUBImZ2ZoomfxHwA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 20 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @l4m2*

Does not support Mercury.

```javascript
n=>(5-9-(9-6<<n))/~9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k7DVNdSV8NS18zGJk9TU7/O8n9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahoGmpoK@voKCrq6dgoGeOReqrCGSrCG6HFASJmdmaKJn8R8A)

---

## JavaScript (ES7), 27 bytes

Supports Mercury.

```javascript
n=>(k=5,--k+--k*--k**n)/-~9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k4j29ZUR1c3WxuItUBYK09TX7fO8n9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahq5nXlpmXmZJpaamgr6@goKurp2CgZ4JF6oqAxRZczRZQyRZQ3Q5oCRMzszQRM/iPwA)

Comment: `9**.5` => `9-6`

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```java
n->((6<<n)+8f)/''
```

Port of l4m2's C [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161898/79343), thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen). Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##jY09C8IwFEXnZPYHvK0J0qqLCFanrk4dxSEmqaSmr6VJCyL97TF@4KrT43LPPa8Wo0jbTmOtrqEbztZIkFY4BwdhEO6UGPS6r4TUUDwjqWwrPCjjvECpWawB@ZaSiZLPPjY@nrE1CppoYaXvDV6OJxD9xfGXpQAFOwiY7hlb5zny@abii2SWBEKijJQ353WTtYPPujj2FpnKvk@XnP@GVn9Bb2qiU3gA).

## Java 8, <s>30</s> 24 bytes

```java
n->(9-5+(9-6<<n))/(5f+5)
```

My original approach; admittedly, it's not very creative. Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##jY09D4IwEIbn8itubENAHTAxohOrE6NxqG0xxXIltJAYw2@v9SOuutzl8j73vC2feGZ7ha28hn48Gy1AGO4cHLhGuCdEo1dDw4WC6nmSxljuQWrnOQpFYwzItgmZE/L5j4mPa7JaQhcttPaDxsvxBHy4OPayVCBhBwGzPd1kRRrHuiyRsQUtmrRggZCoJPXNedXldvR5HxXeIJX5t3rJ2G9o9Rf0puZkDg8).

Thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for golfing 6 bytes.

Comment: -4 bytes by creating a [port of _l4m2_'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161895/52210): `n->((6<<n)+8)*-.5/~9` (result is a double instead of a float now).

Comment: -2 more bytes by changing `*+8)-.5/~9` to `+8f)/''`. (unprintable ASCII with value 20). [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jY09C8IwFEXnZPYHvK0J0qqLCFanrk4dxSEmqaSmr6VJCyL97TF@4KrT43LPPa8Wo0jbTmOtrqEbztZIkFY4BwdhEO6UGPS6r4TUUDwjqWwrPCjjvECpWawB@ZaSiZLPPjY@nrE1CppoYaXvDV6OJxD9xfGXpQAFOwiY7hlb5zny@abii2SWBEKijJQ353WTtYPPujj2FpnKvk@XnP@GVn9Bb2qiU3gA) Credit to _l4m2_ again, this time [his C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161898/52210).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen What's the point of the "unprintable ASCII with value 20"? [Type `20` instead and it just works. Oh, and it's 1 byte shorter...](https://tio.run/##jY09D4IwFEXn9le8sY0B0cGYiE6sTozGobaFFMsroYXEGH471o@46vRyc889rxGjSFynsVHXuRsu1kiQVngPR2EQ7pQYDLqvhNRQPCOprBMBlPFBoNQs1oB8R8lEyWcfmxDP6IyCNlpYGXqD9ekMoq89f1kKULCHGZMDY5s8R77YVny5zmZCoouUNx90m7ohpF3cBotMpd@fGee/odVf0Jua6DQ/AA)

Comment: Oh... Didn't see the restriction. Sorry...

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Np. I made the same mistake on someone else's answer at first, suggesting `/2` instead of `*.5`. :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>14</s>  8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-3 thanks to miles (use of `æ«`, bit-shift) ..and -3 more by golfing from there

```
6æ«+8H÷⁵
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/s8LJDq7UtPA5vf9S49f///4aGAA)**

#### How?

```
6æ«+8H÷⁵ - Link: number, N (including -inf)
6        - literal six
 æ«      - bit-shift = 6*(2^N)
   +8    - add eight = 6*(2^N)+8
     H   - halve = 3*(2^N)+4
       ⁵ - literal ten
      ÷  - divide = (3*(2^N)+4)/10
```

Comment: Isn't something incredibly boring like `“¤‘æ«+“¥‘÷⁵` a valid solution too?

Comment: Hadn't thought of bitshift, so probably

Comment: ...yep that and more, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
zzrkr^zz+*8z/+A/p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b/i/qqoouyiuqkpby6JKX9tRv@C/oUFAMld0Sp6pRQCGZHJscQiXQXFmdE5mTkhFTqahdkpxprOdU2xKsVPFfwA)

Assuming *n* is all that's on the stack, we get the stack depth twice to push `1` and `2` onto the stack. Reverse these and use the `1` to set our precision (`k`). Reverse so that our stack is now `2 n`, exponentiate (`^`). Use `z` to get stack depth twice, again pushing `1` and `2` onto the stack. Add them (`+`) to get `3`, multiply (`*`) by our previous result. Push `8`, get the stack depth with `z` to push `2`, divide these (`/`) to push `4`. Add this (`+`) to the previous result, and divide by 10 (`A/`). Finally, `p`rint.

Knocked off a byte using `8z/` instead of `zF+v` to make a `4`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>54</s> <s>42</s> 35 bytes

```
.+
@@@$&$*_@@@@
+`@_
_@@
M`@
.$
.$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@by8HBQUVNRSseSDtwaSc4xHMBmVy@CQ5ceipApPb/vwGXIZcRlwmXKZcZlzmXoSEA) Link includes test cases. Edit: Saved 12 bytes thanks to @Leo. Explanation:

```
.
@@@$&$*_@@@@
```

Generate a pseudo-binary number using `@` as 1 and `_` as `*2`, having `3` as the first digit and `4` as the last digit, thus representing `3*2^n+4`.

```
+`@_
_@@
```

Convert to unary.

```
M`@
```

Convert to decimal.

```
.$
.$&
```

Divide by 10.

Comment: I think you need `.+` on the first line, otherwise it won't work on numbers higher than 9. I see a couple of possible golfs: 1) you can save 1 byte by triplicating each `@` and then appending four more `@` instead of doing it all at once. 2) To divide by 10 you can just convert to decimal and then insert the point before the last digit. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@by0FFTUUrnks7wSGeK97BgQsIgaQKiHTg8k1w4NJTASK1//8NuAy5jLhMuEy5zLjMuQwNAQ "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online").
(By the way, you could convert it to Retina 1 by changing `$*_` to `*` and `M` to `C`)

Comment: @Leo Whoops, I was really overthinking that decimal conversion, thanks! You also inspired me to find an even better way of multiplying by three and adding four. But I hadn't realised we needed to support that many planets; I don't even know of a solar system with that many.

Comment: Yeah, the number of planets is a bit weird, but one of the test cases is 11... Anyway, your `3*2^n+4` algorithm is amazing, nice work!

Answer (score 3):

## Google Sheets, <s>27</s> <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
=((8-5)*(7-5)^A5+9-5)/(5+5)
=(9^.5*(7-5)^A5+9-5)/(5+5)
=(9^.5*(7-5)^A5+9-5)*.7/7
=(7-5)^A5*(.8-.5)+.9-.5
```

Take input from cell A5.

For a no-digit version (except the A5 is unavoidable),

```
=(code("")*code("")^a5+code(""))/code("
```

(there is a trailing newline)

Comment: How is A5 unavoidable?

Answer (score 3):

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 325 bytes

```
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 9
> 6
> Input
>> 5-6
>> 5-55
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 7
>> 9+9
>> 9*7
>> 55-56
>> 57⋅58
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
> 8
>> 58+55
>> 59+56
>> 66÷65
>> Output 67
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsGCCxVbArEZEHvmFZSWcNnZKZjqmkEoU1MuTOVDAZuD3G@pbQmmtMA8U6B3IN4yf9TdaopDJ1DaQhvkbSDDUhuiwczs8HYzsJB/aQkwiBTMzP//NzQEAA)

Let me outline the problem with using Whispers:

Whispers is a single-expression, line-based programming language. Each line consists of a single mathematical expression. However, if the line starts with `>>`, the numbers used have different values to what they would normally express.

When a line begins with `>` (such as `> 8`) the value returned is the number shown, so that example would return `8` when referenced. `Input` returns an evaluated line from STDIN.

However, when the line starts with `>>`, such as `>> 5-6`, the numbers are interpreted as line references, i.e. the above line would call line `5`, then line `6`, then subtract the results.

Let's create a program that half-sticks to the rules first. This program doesn't use `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4` to represent those numbers, but does use them as line references. This 'half' solution is 96 bytes:

```
> 6
> 9
> Input
>> 2-1
>> 1=1
>> 4-5
>> 6*3
>> 7⋅4
>> 6+6
>> 8+9
>> 2+5
>> 10÷11
>> Output 12
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsGMy07BEog98wpKS7js7BSMdA1BlKEtmDLRNQVRZlrGIMr8UXerCZivbQaiLLQtwVq0wYoMDQ5vNwTr8i8tAZqmYAi0wdAQAA)

Unfortunately, the challenge disallows the *characters* `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` from appearing in the program, irregardless of what they represent. So, to work around this, we have to use line references with only the numbers `5`, `6`, `7`, `8` and `9` in their digits. This has the consequence that we cannot use any lines between `10` and `54`, which is what the massive chain of `> 8` are. In fact, all lines that represent a forbidden line reference has `> 8`, just for consistency.

So, let's remove those lines, but pretend they're still there, we just can't see them:

```
> 9
> 6
> Input
>> 5-6
>> 5-55
> 7
>> 9+9
>> 9*7
>> 55-56
>> 57⋅58
>> 58+55
>> 59+56
>> 66÷65
>> Output 67
```

Which is a very similar structure to the 'half' solution. Here's how this shortened solution works, with an input `11`:

```
> 9		; Line  5: Yield 9
> 6		; Line  6: Yield 6
> Input		; Line  7: Yield a line of input (11)
>> 5-6		; Line  8: Yield 3 	-	9 - 6
>> 5-55		; Line  9: Yield 2	-	9 - 7
⋮
> 7		; Line 55: Yield 7
>> 9+9		; Line 56: Yield 4	-	2 + 2
>> 9*7		; Line 57: Yield 2048 	-	2 ^ 11
>> 55-56	; Line 58: Yield 3	-	7 - 4
>> 57⋅58	; Line 59: Yield 6144	-	2048 ⋅ 3
⋮
>> 58+55	; Line 65: Yield 10	-	3 + 7
>> 59+56	; Line 66: Yield 6148	-	6144 + 4
>> 66÷65	; Line 67: Yield 614.8	-	6148 ÷ 10
>> Output 67	; Line 68: Output 614.8
```

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 27 bytes

```
l$:?!vll-+$:+!
:*lrl<;n,a+l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P0fFyl6xLCdHV1vFSluRy0orpyjHxjpPJ1E75////7plhoYA)

Some heavy abuse of the stack length command (`l`) command here. Luckily, most of the numbers needed are in ascending order. Takes input through the `-v` flag

Comment: Don't you need to add a byte for the flag?

Comment: Just now saw your other comment. If that's the convention now I will gladly use it.

Comment: @Hohmannfan For reference, here's the [meta question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/76162) where it was decided that command line flags are now free

Answer (score 3):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 13 bytes

```
³+<*/Ⅹ+⅖
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPv/0GZtGy39R60rtR@1TvtvrVCcWKmgpBKvYGunUJ2moBJfq6SQll@kEGdo8B8A)

This formula uses Unicode characters with the right numeric values to stand in for the forbidden characters.

- ³ - SUPERSCRIPT THREE - value = 3
- Ⅹ - ROMAN NUMERAL TEN - value = 10
- ⅖ - VULGAR FRACTION TWO FIFTHS - value = 0.4

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```python
lambda n:((6-9<<n)-~-5)/~9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPSkPDTNfSxiZPU7dO11RTv87yf1p@kUKmQmaeQlFiXnqqhqGpphWXQkFRZl6JRppGpqbmfwA)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>38</s> <s>34</s> <s>31</s> <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```python
lambda n:((6-9<<n)-9.+5)/~9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPSkPDTNfSxiZPU9dST9tUU7/O8n9afpFCpkJmnkJRYl56qoahqaYVl0JBUWZeiUKaRqbmfwA)

---

Saved:

- -4 bytes, thanks to Giuseppe
- -1 byte, thanks to Jonathan Allan

Comment: f(0) gives 0.55 instead of 0.7?

Comment: @mdahmoune Fixed

Comment: use negative numbers to save a byte: `lambda n:((6-9<<n)-~-5)/~9`

Answer (score 2):

## [Symbolic Python](https://github.com/FTcode/Symbolic-Python), <s>69</s> 56 bytes

```
___=_==_
__=-~___
_=__**~-_*-~__+___+___**-___
_/=__-~__
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/Pj7eNt7WNp4LSOvWAXlcQH68lladbrwWiK8dD8FaWrpgSX2gLEj8////hoYA) Implements `(3*2^(n-1)+2)/5`

#### How?

```
# Input is stored in _ initially

___=_==_         # ___ = True (=1)
__=-~___         # __  = -~1 = 1 + 1 = 2
_=__**~-_*-~__+___+___**-___
# _ = 2**~-_ * -~2 + 1 + 1**-1 = 2**(n-1) * 3 + 1 + 1.0 = 3 * 2**(n-1) + 2.0
_/=__-~__        # _   = _ / (2 -~ 2) = _ / (2 + -~2) = _ / (2 + 2+1) = _ / 5 

# Implicit output of _
```

Comment: Never thought I'd actually see someone submit an answer in this stupid esolang I decided to make!

Answer (score 2):

## [Mathics](https://github.com/mathics/Mathics), 34 bytes

```
d[n_]:=((9-6)*(8-6)^n+(9-5))/(5+5)
```

[Try it here!](https://mathics.angusgriffith.com/#cXVlcmllcz1kJTVCbl8lNUQlM0ElM0QoKDktNikqKDgtNiklNUVuJTJCKDktNSkpJTJGKDUlMkI1KSZxdWVyaWVzPWQlNUItSW5maW5pdHklNUQmcXVlcmllcz1kJTVCMCU1RCZxdWVyaWVzPWQlNUIxJTVEJnF1ZXJpZXM9ZCU1QjExJTVE)

My first time golfing in Mathics, so there's probably a bit more optimizing to be done.

Comment: `((9-6)(8-6)^#+(9-5))/(5+5)&`

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
‘⁺
¢*+Ḥ$Ç⁺÷⁵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4xHjbu4Di3S0n64Y4nK4XYg7/D2R41b////b2gIAA)

About time for an explanation

### How it works

```
‘⁺        - Helper link. Can be called monadically, or niladically.
          - When called niladically, `0` is the left argument.
 ⁺        - Perform the previous command twice:
‘         -   Increment the left argument

¢*+Ḥ$Ç⁺÷⁵ - Main link. 1 argument: n
¢*        - Yield 2n
    $     - Perform the next two commands on 2n:
   Ḥ      -   Halve.           Yields 2n-1
  +       -   Add to 2n.       Yields 3⋅2n
     Ç    - Add 2.             Yields 3⋅2n + 2
      ⁺   - Add 2 again.       Yields 3⋅2n + 4
        ⁵ - Yield 10
       ÷  - Divide by 10.      Yields (3⋅2n + 4)/10
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
â╬╫▓♠âε
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=83ced7b20683ee&i=0.0%0A1.0%0A11.0&a=1&m=2)

PackedStax source encoding makes the character restrictions trivial.  Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented this is the same program.

```
|2  2 to the power
3*  multiply by 3
4+  add 4
A/  divide by 10
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7C2%092+to+the+power%0A3*%09multiply+by+3%0A4%2B%09add+4%0AA%2F%09divide+by+10&i=0.0%0A1.0%0A11.0&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 2):

## BRASCA, 29 bytes

```
ig$}}:a$^A}:a*A}+:l/ml%mn'.on
```

[Try it!](https://sjoerdpennings.github.io/brasca-online/?code=ig%24%7D%7D%3Aa%24%5EA%7D%3Aa*A%7D%2B%3Al%2Fml%25mn%27.on&stdin=11)

BRASCA only supports whole integers, so I had to spend a couple bytes to at least get one decimal, to pass the test cases.

### Explanation

```
                               - Implicit input
ig                             - Turn 0-9 into the actual numbers and concatenate
  $}}:a$^                      -    2^n
         A}:a*                 - (3*
              A}+              -       +4)
                 :l/           -          /10
                    ml%mn'.on  - Get the first decimal, and print the number.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
ó∙☻√ΓΣ♂/
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9tYXRoZ29sZv//w7PiiJnimLviiJrOk86j4pmCL///MAoxCjEx)

Actually the same amount of bytes as the straight-forward approach without [restricted-source](/questions/tagged/restricted-source):

```
ó3*4+♀√/
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wZmMtE@1HMxsedczS///fgMuQy9AQAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
ó         # Take 2 to the power of the (implicit) input-integer
 ∙        # Triplicate it
  ☻       # Push 16
   √      # Take the square-root of that: 4.0
    Γ     # Wrap the four values on the stack into a list
     Σ    # Sum this list together
      ♂/  # Divide it by 10
          # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)

ó         # Take 2 to the power of the (implicit) input-integer
 3*       # Multiply it by 3
   4+     # Add 4
     ♀√/  # Divide it by the square-root of 100 (10.0),
          # since `/` will be integer-division if both arguments are integers
          # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# .NET, 18 bytes

```csharp
n=>((6<<n)+8f)/''
```

`''` is an unprintable ASCII character with value `20`.

Port of [*@l4m2*'s C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161898/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jcyxCsIwEIDhPbMPcFsT1KqLCE27CE52cnAOMYGD9AK9UxDps0cExVH37/89L30eQ/HJMUP/UAAsTtDD6c4ShvpwJW@RZAExZScdRGihUNtpvbWWzHwXzaqaVaVR3/aW8QK9Q9LmdYTPbJ@Jcwr1eUQJR6Sgo14b0/wym3/MG01qKk8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 25 bytes

```ruby
->n{6-5.6+6%5.7*(9-7)**n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6v2kzXVM9M20zVVM9cS8NS11xTSyuv9n9BaUmxQlq0QSwXlGWIYBnG/gcA)

Output ±ε due to float imprecision.

Answer (score 1):

## Whispers v2, 91 bytes

```
> Input
>> 9*56
>> 57⋅8
>> 58+7
>> 59÷6
> 5
>> ≺6
>> ≺7
>> ≺8
>> 5÷9
>> Output 65
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0hMvOTsFSy9QMRJuaP@putQCzLLTNwbTl4e1AKQVTEOdR5y4zKG0OpSGKD2@3BNH@pSVAAxXMTP//NzQEAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 38 bytes

```powershell
(.9-.6)*[math]::pow(8-6,"$args")+.9-.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0PPUlfPTFMrOjexJCPWyqogv1zDQtdMR0klsSi9WElTGyRv@v//f0NDAA)

-11 bytes thanks to @mazzy

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0PPUlfPTFMrOjexJCPWyqogv1zDQtdMR0klsSi9WElTGyRv@v//f0NDAA "PowerShell – Try It Online").

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 55 bytes

```lua
o=#" "t=o+o function x(m)return((o+t)*t^m+t^t)/(5*t)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TccxCoAwDAXQ3VMUXRI7qINjr1IQrSBoIuUXevvoIri9d5bFTEPXuhZBvbq9yIpDxVW6OCeULETqwT3i5RHBA809OMlmdz4EVGlkbj5Pf7@xBw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 41 bytes

A port of [@O.O.Balance's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161892/110802).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnUM2loJCSmqaQC@RoJBalF1spOBYVJVZGB5cUZealx2paKYTmZZYo2CpU/y9LzFFIsfLMK7G1c8vJTyyxzbO107DUNdUGEmY2Nnmamvoapmnappr/FYCAC0QUAA0pycnTSNEw0NREEzHEFIEI1XLV/gcA)

```scala
val d:Int=>Float=n=>(9-5+(9-6<<n))/(5f+5)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
à╙i;?«°☻
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=85d3693b3faef802&i=0%0A1%0A11&m=2)

I think this is a little bit unfair because the original code contains digits, but PackedStax doesn't... here's what it unpacks to:

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 bytes

```
|23*4+A:_
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7C23*4%2BA%3A_&i=0%0A1%0A11&m=2)

```
|23*4+A:_
|2        # 2**n
  3*      # *3
    4+    # +4
      A:_ # float divided by 10
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
ET⇧⇧₀/
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJFVOKHp+KHp+KCgC8iLCIiLCIwIl0=)

`₀` != `0`

### Explained

```
ET⇧⇧₀/
E      # 2 ** n
 T     # * 3
  ⇧⇧   # + 2 + 2
    ₀/ # divided by 10
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/tree/main), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ODḌ+ƙƙT/
```

Port of [Emigna's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161886/114446).

##### Explanation

```python
ODḌ+ƙƙT/  # Implicit input
O         # Push 2 ** input
 DḌ       # Duplicate and double
   +      # Add (triple)
    ƙƙ    # Add 2 twice (add 4)
      T/  # Divide by ten
          # Implicit output
```

---

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 13 bytes

```
U(U Ea*@PI)/t
```

Contains no digits at all. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhZrQzVCFVwTtRwCPDX1SyBiUKkl0YaGsVA2AA)

#### Explanation

Uses a slightly modified formula:

$$\frac{3\cdot(2^n+1)+1}{10}$$

```lisp
U(U Ea*@PI)/t
     a         ; Command-line input
    E          ; 2 to that power
  U            ; Increment
      *        ; Times
       @PI     ; the first character of pi
U(        )    ; Increment that result
           /t  ; Divide by 10
```

Answer (score 0):

## x86 machine code, <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
6a 03                   push   0x3
58                      pop    eax
d3 e0                   shl    eax,cl
04 04                   add    al,0x4
50                      push   eax
db 04 24                fild   DWORD PTR [esp]
6a 0a                   push   0xa
de 74 24 00             fidiv  WORD PTR [esp+0x0]
58                      pop    eax
58                      pop    eax
c3                      ret
```

Pretty straightforward, except for two little details:

1. It's enough to add 4 to `al` - adding it to `eax` is 1 byte longer
2. `[esp+0x0]` - explicit displacement equal to 0 is needed to avoid the forbidden byte `0x34` (ASCII `4`) in the instruction's encoding; thanks to [l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2) for the idea!

Comment: `6A 03 58 D3 E0 04 04 50 DB 04 24 6A 0A DE 74 24 00 58 58 C3`?

Comment: `6A 03 58 D3 E0 04 04 50 89 E7 DB 07 58 6A 0A DE 37 58 C3` with `edi` changed

Comment: Might work with a suitable calling convention; I only know how to work with `fastcall` though, on MS Windows.